Playing RTP stream on Android 4.1.2 (Jelly Bean)
I'll try to keep it quick. Using FFMPEG I started a stream on my PC. Here is the code:
import subprocess

def start_stream():
    command = [
        'ffmpeg',
        '-f', 'gdigrab',  # Desktop capture (Windows)
        '-framerate', '15',  # Low framerate for higher performance
        '-i', 'desktop',  # Capture desktop
        '-c:v', 'libx264',  # Video codec (H.264)
        '-preset', 'ultrafast',  # Ultra-fast encoding preset for minimal latency
        '-tune', 'zerolatency',  # Zero latency for real-time streaming
        '-x264opts', 'keyint=15:min-keyint=15:no-scenecut',  # Frequent keyframes
        '-b:v', '500k',  # Low bitrate to minimize data usage and reduce latency
        '-s', '800x480',  # Resolution fits phone screen and helps performance
        '-max_delay', '0',  # No buffering, instant frame output
        '-flush_packets', '1',  # Flush packets immediately after encoding
        '-f', 'rtp',  # Use mpegts as the container for RTP stream
        'rtp://192.168.72.26:1234',  # Stream over UDP to localhost on port 1234
        '-sdp_file', 'stream.sdp'  # Create SDP file
    ]
    
    try:
        print("Starting stream...")
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nStream interrupted")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting screen capture...")
    start_stream()

Now, when I start the stream I can connect to it in VLC when I open up the stream.sdp file. Using the same method I can open up the stream on my iPhone, but when I try to open it on my old Android phone the stream connects but the screen is black. However, when I turn the screen I can see the first frame that was sent to the phone. Why does the stream not work?
I will be thankful for any and all advice :)
